# how to change model in pusher

Tags: laravel, pusher

I recently learn pusher by read tutorial in google and in the tutorial he use model but im not using model I use raw query so his code for function boot is

```
public function boot(){
    Item::observe(ItemObserver::class);
}
```

Item is his model name , so if im not using model what code that I use to replace model from function boot?

Comment: What tutorial you are referring to? What do you need to emit? Pusher helps you to broadcast events, the use of a model is not related to the execution of the event (of course you can do it, but is not mandatory in order to make Pusher work).

Comment: tutorial make notification @HCK

Comment: The link mate, so I can see the part of the code that uses the model object to guide you to the solution @bramastaVic